# Stop webview from opening and do something else

Tags: android, url, webview, textview

How would I stop a webview from opening after I click on a link? I also need to extract the URL address so I can put it into a string.

Answer (score 1):

Set WebViewClient :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

         @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO do something with url
            return true;
        } 
      });
```